# Not able to read '@' symbol from a csv file in karate

Tags: karate, web-api-testing, feature-file

I am using a csv file which has got one column email and its value contains @
And when I try that value to read in my feature I am getting exception.
Both Feature file and csv are in same location in project directory.

## Csv:

username,password
sample@yopmail.com,abc123
sample2@yopmail.com,abc123

## My Feature looks like this:

**NOTE** that to make it work, I have appended @yopmail.com BUT this can't be done if my email id is @gmail.com or @mailinator.com or any other email.

**Feature**: Login Feature

**Background**:

- url url

**Scenario Outline**: Login with Valid credentials

Given path '/oauth/token' 
When header Authorization = applicationToken 
And header Content-Type = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' 
And form field grant_type = 'password' 
And form field username = '<**username**>@yopmail.com' 
And form field password = '<**password**>' 
And method post 
Then status 200 
def accessToken = "Bearer "+response.access_token 
print accessToken

Comment: maybe this is a special character for csv (which you have to escape) or maybe there is a bug in karate. if you can't figure this out, try switching to JSON. else please contribute code or follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue